# Compiling a 32 bit fortran program on 64 bit Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, fortran, linker-errors, 32bit-64bit

I have a 32 bit fortran code that I need to compile on a 64 bit machine. I researched and found that it is possible to do it. I installed gfortran-multilib to compile it. But I got errors like this:

```
gfortran -lm bessj.o bessj0.o bessj1.o bessj2.o caxcb.o cgemp.o cmemcpy.o   four1.o gemp.o getdata.o qsbstab.o qsfftinv.o qshkpsv.o qshksh.o qskern.o qslayer.o qsmainC.o qsmatinv.o qsmatrix.o qsmoment.o qspsv.o qsqmodel.o qssh.o qssublay.o qswaveno.o qswvint.o wavelet.o -o qsmainC.0
/usr/bin/ld: i386 architecture of input file `bessj0.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
/usr/bin/ld: i386 architecture of input file `bessj2.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
/usr/bin/ld: i386 architecture of input file `caxcb.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
/usr/bin/ld: i386 architecture of input file `cgemp.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
```

Then I used -m32 flag as suggested in one of the threads here in stackoverflow. And I found out that some of the subroutines have 32-bit architecture while some have 64-bit architecture. I am getting error for the other files now, like this:

```
gfortran -m32 -lm bessj.o bessj0.o bessj1.o bessj2.o caxcb.o cgemp.o cmemcpy.o four1.o gemp.o getdata.o qsbstab.o qsfftinv.o qshkpsv.o qshksh.o qskern.o qslayer.o qsmainC.o qsmatinv.o qsmatrix.o qsmoment.o qspsv.o qsqmodel.o qssh.o qssublay.o qswaveno.o qswvint.o wavelet.o -o qsmainC.0
/usr/bin/ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `bessj.o' is incompatible with i386 output
/usr/bin/ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `bessj1.o' is incompatible with i386 output
/usr/bin/ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `four1.o' is incompatible with i386 output
/usr/bin/ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `qsfftinv.o' is incompatible with i386 output
```

Is there any way to compile this code? Can someone please suggest?

Comment: How did you get the .o files? Show all of your commands, not just the last one. You need to compile from source. Also give us details about your operating system.

Comment: It seems the .o files were included in the directory from the source itself. I tried 'make clean' before but it did not work. This time I deleted them manually. When I deleted these .o files, it compiled successfully. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like some of your .o files are 32 bit and some 64 bit.

Notice that the files reported as incompatible in the first command are different from those reported in the other command with `-m32`.

Recompile all of them consistently.

Comment: You are right. I recompiled by deleting the .o files. Thank you.